# Passing parameter into Cypher query node_auto_index

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data

I'm trying to pass a parameter into the Cypher query node_auto_index without any luck.

DecisionRepository.class:

```
@Query("START d=node:node_auto_index(':text') MATCH (d:Decision) RETURN d") 
List<Decision> searchDecisions(String text);
```

Usage:

```
List<Decision> searchDecisions = decisionRepository.searchDecisions("name:aDbma~ OR name:mosyl~");
```

Is it possible and if so where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [query parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html)

```
START d=node:node_auto_index({myLuceneQuery}) RETURN d;
```

Then send `"name:aDbma~ OR name:mosyl~"` as `{myLuceneQuery}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, works now ! I forgot to add @Param annotation in a signature of the method - @Param("text")